# A stranger wrote this on his arm

Tags: knowledge, symbols

A stranger walked up to my friend and drew these symbols on his arm with a Sharpie. I have no idea what they mean.

[image: Cryptic writing on arm]
[image: Cryptic writing on arm]

They were written on his right and left arm. The second picture might be upside down.

I imagine that they are based upon fictional languages. If so, what languages, and what do these messages read?

Comment: While the first language was easily found, it might be a good idea to ask this on Scifi/Fantasy. The people over there might know this, as maybe someone remembers seeing something similar.

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Comment: @Rubio Nobody has found the solution to the second picture

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the first one:

> "kuestion" or "chestion" (maybe they meant "question"?) in [Aurebesh](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Aurebesh) from Star Wars
>
> [image]

The second one *might* be:

> Hebrew, [as suggested at SFF](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/179589/82909). I don't know the language at all, but the rightmost character could be dalet or zayin with a sheva diacritic, like this (sorry, it's really tiny):
>  זְ

Comment: It _is_ "question," but the first character is backwards.

Answer (score 1):

The first is

> [Aurebesh](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Aurebesh) for `QUESTION`.

The second doesn't seem to be from the same source. Its letterforms didn't pop up in several Google searches and lists of fictional languages, so I had no luck. (That T with the two dots seems distinctive - nothing I tried had it, so the only way to find the script might just be someone recognizing it.)

Comment: It's good to know that the writing has a meaning. I was afraid it was simply gibberish. But now I think the second one has a meaning, albeit obscure. Remember, it may be upside down.

Comment: Second One https://in.pinterest.com/pin/382806037061971461/?lp=true maybe this.

Comment: that pintrest link doesn't work for me - which?