# Replace the odd one out image

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge

[image]

One of the following images from A,B,C,D,E is incorrectly matched. Which one is it and which image from the 3 depicted below will replace it?

Comment: @Evargalo : I think your answer is a proper answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image appears to have been taken from this one:

> [image: The Mantoran Language from LEGO Bionicle]
>  [Sourced from here](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/bionicle/images/6/67/The_Matoran_Language.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20081214121005)

In which case the solution would be

> Replace 'E' with the first image, two horizontal lines.

I personally can't see any rhyme or reason to the sequence, so if you don't recognise it (or stumble upon it whilst trying to find an answer to [another question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/59629/10330) - link kindly provided by @prog_SAHIL; a familiar name...) there's no obvious way to deduce the answer.

Comment: That's what the knowledge tag is for.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is the answer the OP is waiting for, but such puzzles typically allow various reasonnings and different interpretations.

> I would replace the B-image by the second image below,
>  so that each image has exactly one 'eye', i.e. one small round.

Admittedly, this proposal doesn't explain how the images are generated as a whole. For instance, I've no clue what image could accompany the letter F - or if it even makes sense to look for the F-image.